Is there a label decorator to show the Maven groupId and artifactId in Eclipse?
Unfortunately we have some projects where the SCM directory name, the Eclipse project name (.project file) and the Maven artifactId are all different.
There is a decorator to show the SCM path, but I couldn't find anything for groupId and artifactId.


What is preventing you from changing the project name?

Mainly colleagues who are used to the existing order in their workspaces. But I am actually in the process of renaming now. Instead of opening each pom it would have been convenient to see the discrepancies at a glance (gets tedious with 100s of projects)

Also existing build scripts / pipelines... Nothing is easy to change after a while.

The artifact ID and the project name are in the pom.xml and .project files which are both XML files. So it should be easy to write a script that does the synchronization. But of course, a rule should first be determined that will be followed by all developers. Build scripts, pipelines, etc. should not be affected by changing the project name in .project, only if you change the project folder names as well. Regarding to your original question: I don't know of such a feature to show the artifact ID as project label, but it shouldn't be that difficult to implement a plugin that does this.

Yes, I am aware of all this, and I did write a script. I'm just usually trying to find existing tools before rolling my own. Anyway, much appreciate your time looking into this (and I really like your videos about new eclipse features)
